# How to capture a multiline string having a match on each line?

Tags: regex

I have a multiline text field and need to test if each line matches a pattern.
The field might look like this:

```
1xABCD
9xDEFGHIJK
7xAJDKSLD
2xA
```

The pattern is this: `\dx\w.*`

The number of lines is from 1 to X.

I was trying `^\d+x\w.*${1,}`  or  `\d+x\w.*\r\n{1,}`

Thank you

Comment: Use `^\d+x\w+(?:\r?\n\d+x\w+)*$`

Comment: it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\d+x\w+(?:\r?\n\d+x\w+)*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+x\w+` - 1+ digits, `x` and then 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `(?:\r?\n\d+x\w+)*` - a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) that matches 0 or more (`*`) occurrences of:

  - `\r?\n` - an optional CR and an LF symbol
  - `\d+x\w+` - 1+ digits, `x` and then 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lgmx1j/1) (note the text pasted in the regex101.com has LF only line endings).